# I’m trying to rewrite this python code to php

Tags: python, php, crc32

I want to convert this python function to php but I don’t know how to rewrite some functions in php from python

```
def video_crc32(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        hex = binascii.hexlify(content)
        count = round(len(content) / 7)
        content = binascii.unhexlify(hex)
        slice = [content[i:i + count] for i in range(0, len(content), count)]
        result = []
        for arr in slice:
            crc = binascii.crc32(arr)
            crcHex = '%08X'.lower() % crc

            res = {"crc32": crcHex, "part": arr}
            result.append(res)
    return result
```

I would appreciate the help, Thank you

Comment: Please show us what you have so far and explain exactly where you're stuck. We're glad to help you sort out _specific_ issues you might run into, but since this isn't a code conversion service, we do need to see your current attempt (with example data, expected output and what you're currently getting)

Comment: Tell us what "some functions" are, and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an elite PHP'er, but i gave a go at trying to convert it and it seems to give the same output as via python, enjoy!

```php
<?php
    function video_crc32($filename) {
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $hex = bin2hex($content);
        $count = round(strlen($content) / 7);
        $content = hex2bin($hex); # ?
        $slice = [];
        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($content); $i+=$count) {
            array_push($slice, substr($content, $i, $i + $count));
        }
        $result = [];
        foreach ($slice as $arr) {
            $crc = crc32($arr);
            $crcHex = sprintf(strtolower('%08X'), $crc);

            $res = ["crc32" => $crcHex, "part" => $arr];
            array_push($result, $res);
        }
        return $result;
    }
?>
```